# Can I use Webpack to inject Google Charts into my project?

Tags: javascript, charts, webpack, ecmascript-6, google-web-component

Is there any way to use Google Charts in a React app? I have found [react-google-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-charts) which I have got working a bit, but it seems to lack much of the API of Google Charts, or is at the very least is undocumented. I'm also a little shy to use something in production that NPM stats show only has ~400 downloads in the last day.

However I can't find Google Charts alone on NPM and no way simply to `import Charts from 'google-charts'` like I had initially expected.

My next thought was to see if there is a way to import a library as a global variable.

1) How can I do that
2) If that's possible how do I include it in a react component like `import { Line } from '???'`

Comment: I'd say that 400 downloads a day is actually pretty good. A red flag would be if there was no issues ever posted. This module has 75 closed issues, and 25 open, so it seems to be active, which is a good sign in my opinion.

Comment: http://blog.arkency.com/2014/09/react-dot-js-and-google-charts/

Answer (score 6):

Use Webpack [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)
By defining a library as `external` webpack simply export the global symbol for the library, much like (say for jQuery)

```
{
    1: function(...) {
        // simplified for illustrating
        module.exports = jQuery;
    }
}
```

So you could do something similar to this:

1. Add a `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>` or newer url from [Charts homepage](https://developers.google.com/chart/)
2. In your webpack configuration add:

   ```
   externals: {
     charts: 'google.charts'  // or any other alias you want, can be a regex too! check Webpack's doc for more
   }
   ```
3. And import it as:

   ```
   import chart from 'charts'
   // do something!
   charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
   ```

Make sure to *load* Google Charts *before loading* your bundle.

For the **ReactJS** part, you need some way to get hold of the native DOM element in your script, by using `refs` or something.

P.S. I am not a react *guy* so maybe someone with react background may help